# New to Python: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'"

Tags: python, django, module

I'm currently working on a tutorial to create an app using Python and Django and am fairly new to the whole process.

I keep getting the message: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'" when running my manage.py file in python

I'm working on a mac if that makes a difference:

Python 3.7

Django 2.0.7

Using virtualenvwrapper

My virtual environment is active

1. dir: my project

   - myproject

     - myproject
     - manage.py
   - venv

Here's my models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Board(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Topic(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, related_name='topics')
    starter = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='topics')


class Post(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField(max_length=4000)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, related_name='posts')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts')
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name='+')
```

I've also changed the top line from "from django.db import models" to "from django.urls import models" as I've read this was recommended on some other posts but have had no success.

What am I missing?


Thanks for the help!

EDIT:

Here is the code from my manage.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: How did you install Django? Are you sure you installed it into your virtualenv, as opposed to installing it into the systemwide site-packages, or even the site-packages for a different Python installation entirely?

Comment: If you're not sure, then, from the shell, make sure your virtualenv active, then do a `pip3 list` and see if `django` appears.

Comment: The file that you show here must be models.py

Comment: Try running `python -m django runserver`: that keeps the Python executable together with its proper Django installation.

Comment: @abarnert Thank you for your response! I just entered pip3 list and this is what I got: Package    Version
---------- -------
Django     2.0.7  
pip        18.0   
pytz       2018.5 
setuptools 40.0.0 
wheel      0.31.1

Comment: @VolArt yes! You're right. I'm sorry about that. I must have been looking at manage.py at the same time and got the two mixed up. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @9769953 Thanks for your suggestion. I tried this, but I ended up with the error: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEBUG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Comment: @2586steps thanks for supplying this link. I did click the link and follow the instructions and my terminal says all requirements have already been satisfied.

Comment: Fun fact: `manage.py` intercepts the `ImportError` (`ModuleNotFoundError` is the Python 3 error, which is a subclass of `ImportError`, and issues a different warning than what you are getting. In other words, you should *not* be getting a "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'" error. So please list your `manage.py` file as well.

Comment: @9769953 Thanks for this helpful piece of information. Forgive me as I'm new to this, but does that mean the wrong version of python is running? I just edited my post and added my manage.py file.

Comment: I don't know; as you can, manage.py would issue a different error message. Is the error you're currently getting just that one line, or is there more traceback? If so, please list the full error traceback, so we can see where it originates.